# IOS building real time application

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer, pubnub

Well i am new to IOS development and want to create a realtime application. In my app i want to update data of tableview cell with real time information like we do with Google Drive shared sheet.

I am not using google drive but its an example. In my app i have a tableview which cell should be updated by realtime data. I have thousands of user groups and any member of group with access to modify can edit that data. So i need to reflect real time change to all other users of particular group.

The data can be anything like image, any formula or anything.

Well for that i have googled and found two options but i am confused which one should i go with.

1. PubNub library
2. NSTimer

   Well i am not sure which one will be best suited for me. I have tried to create a demo app with PubNub but with heard luck i can't do more.

   So can so please suggest me which should i choose or is there any other alternative. I am using Xcode 7.3 with swift 2.3

   Thanx in advance.

Comment: We generally achieve realtime using socket connections, PubNub probably uses Node.JS in background which is best and fastest for RealTime thing, but it comes for a price, you can choose [Node.JS](http://socket.io/) for your development. `NO for NSTimer`

Comment: thank a lot for quick replay...can you please give me some link for socket connection an please elaborate Node.JS usage

Comment: may i know the reason for downvote

Comment: @iphonic actually Objective-C SDK use sockets connection (higher level with NSURLSession) and PubNub servers doesn't use Node.JS for it's real-time operation.

Comment: @HRaval as reason for down vote it may be because there is no real-time component in your setup. If you want to use data from google drive, then you need some kind of polling mechanism and maybe with timer. If you have any service which is able to notify about changes on google drive, you can use PubNub to notify remote clients to fetch data (or send data directly through PubNub if smaller than 32Kb).

Comment: @SerhiiMamontov i am not using google drive....i just gave an example...i want to achieve something like google drive does for shared sheet...in my app i have tableview which cell should be updated with real time data

Comment: @SerhiiMamontov please see my edits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PubNub is not based on Node, however we have many SDKs for over 70+ different languages/platforms, like Node and Swift. The network is a hosted realtime, data stream network (DSN) that the SDKs connect to allowing your app to send and receive messages in realtime around the world in < 1/4 second to 1 or millions of clients.

For more on this, read [How PubNub Works?](https://www.pubnub.com/developers/tech/how-pubnub-works/)

You can use PubNub for free for up to 100 daily active devices and up to 1 million messages per month (plenty for a demo app).

You would use the PubNub Swift SDK to subscribe to publish and subscribe to some channel to update your app.

Please check out our [Swift SDK docs](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/swift/pubnub-swift-sdk) to get started.

Comment: Thanx for explanation but i have large amount of users...and i would prefer to go with free api so i can't use pub nub...i have searched for socket and i feel its perfact for me...any suggestions are welcome

Comment: The cost of free is higher than you think :) If you get to a point where scaling is becoming difficult to manage (and pay for), PubNub and other realtime services offer a < DYI cost solution.